# posting strings and array to php with ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

nothing complicated here. just posting the data using ajax and its not working..

```
     var ttc=$("#lblTot").val();
      var tva=$("#prixTva").val();

      var net=$("#prixNet").val();
      var taxes=[ttc,tva];
      var build="testing1212";



      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'passerCommande.php',
         data: {
            prices : net,
            taxes : taxes,
            build : build,
          },
        });
```

and here is my php file

```
  <?php
    error_reporting(0);

   $itemPrices=$_POST['prices'];
    $taxes=$_POST['taxes'];
    $build=$_POST["build"];

    $date=date("Y-m-d h:i");

    echo "build : ".$build;
    ?>
```

i tried to "echo" the build but its empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 errors in your JS function :
- "type" instead of "method" (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- you have an extra comma after "build" in the data values
- you have an extra comma after the data values

JS is not as permissive as PHP

```
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url:'passerCommande.php',
    data: {
        prices : net,
        taxes : taxes,
        build : build
    }
});
```

And you should use var_dump() instead of echo function

Comment: fixed all that , var_dump($build) gave me a result of null

Comment: why the code is not working after fixing what you mentioned ?

Comment: Can you post a var_dump($_POST) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's call after page loaded if yes please check console by inspect elements and check errors and send me or if you don't know please run

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     // your code.....
});
```

Comment: actually my code is inside a function i call onclick of a button. and no i have no errors

Comment: Ok add a ,success: function (data){ console. log(data); }     in ajax function

Comment: should i put the button that calls the function wich has the ajax code inside a form ? cause i am doing that.  i removed "taxes" nothing changed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to stringify your output: 
`$json = json_encode($build);
  echo $json;`

Comment: i got "null" result